# C# / MigraDoc: Long table breaking across pages, top and bottom border

Tags: c#, border, pdfsharp, page-break, migradoc

I have a long table in C#, MigraDoc, which splits across two pages.
I need only outer borders.
When the table is split, the top border and the bottom border will not be visible.
Is there a way to make them visible?
(It cannot be determined where the page break will be.)

Answer (score 0):

For top border you could use the `row.HeadingFormat = true` and then set the top border on it like this:

```
var table = new Table();
var headingRow = table.AddRow();
headingRow.HeadingFormat = true;
headingRow.Borders.Top.Width = 1;
// your other table content here
```

I'm currently looking into how to do the same thing for the bottom table border, but it seems that there's no way to do it.

Comment: It would be great help .If you can update here the solution for bottom table border .